# Airship - what is the workflow to create these parts

Tags: modeling

[image]
[image]

I am looking for ideas on how to create and attach the puffed out sections along the bottom of this airship that red arrow is pointing to. There are plenty of tutorials on airships but nothing to help add bumps like this to such an odd shape. After many hours, I can't move forward. An suggestions are most welcome.

Cheers Ivan

Comment: I am not sure what those are but you could probably make it with low poly spheres, just flatten them and try to connect them to loopcuts of your ship... Or maybe it would be logical to make it with height map and textures

Answer (score 7):

You could cut a circle on a cylinder with the *Knife Project* tool then rearrange the topology this way:

[image]

Give an *Array* and *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your cylinder, work the topology again:

[image]

Give it a *Lattice* in order to deform it:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots . Could you please attach the blend file so I can follow your workflow?

Comment: sure, see my edit

Comment: Thanks for the Blend file. I am surprised you know the name of the airship.

Comment: thanks to Google Image  ;)